# How much does performance suffer when both reading and writing occurs simultaneously on a Redis slave?

Tags: performance, redis, replication

I want to build a system where a master periodically updates changes to its slave, the slave is read only. How much would my read operation suffer given that redis is single threaded. I would have to entertain multiple read requests and output the results in real time.

Comment: It depends on many things: read/write pattern, configuration, data size and so on. You have to do some tests with your data.